# Can you configure 2013 App part to use different URL in dev and production

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, app-part

In the AppPart Elements.xml we add

```
<Content Type="html" Src="<URL to app>?{StandardTokens}" />
```

Is there a way to configure this URL to change based on the environment? Either get it from a list or the web.config? If not we need to change the URL each time we want to publish the app to a different environment.

Answer (score 1):

I also met with the same requirement.  But actually we could not modify the SRC attribute.  Then, I found a work around for this.  Let the AppPart renders on the page.  It gets rendered as a iFrame.  By using a Javascript, let us modify the SRC attribute of the iFrame dynamically.

The sample script would be,

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    IFrameSRC = $('iframe').get(0).src;
    alert("IframeeSRC : " + IFrameSRC);

    if (IFrameSRC != "") {

        $('iframe').get(0).src = "NEW URL";
    }

});
```

Comment: There is another way? And what about Reverse Proxy?

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand your question
~remoteAppUrl
is the Token you insert for  and the matching will be done in SharePoint with the information you provide on /_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx